# CouchDB dump to file and load from file

Tags: load, couchdb, backup, dump, database-backups

I cannot replicate between two couchdb servers, so I would like to dump to file from one server and load from file into the other server.

I used this statement to dump and it worked fine:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/<DATABASE_NAME>/_all_docs?include_docs=true > FILE.txt
```

But when I used this statement to load:

```
curl -d @FILE.txt -H “Content-Type: application/json” -X POST http://localhost:5984/<DATABASE_NAME>/_bulk_docs
```

it failed like this:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Host not found {"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: will this backup the revisions of each of the documents ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As said, you should use the `"` and not the `“` as argument of the `-H` option

If you are a Linux or MacOSX user you can use the [couchdb-dump](https://github.com/animamea/couchdb-dump) tool, which basically works on bash shell.

It dumps the database on a local file (ASCII text file), formatted as requested by http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API

Then you can restore it with the bulk document upload or with the couchdb-dump restore tool included in the package.

This is the link to the tool: https://github.com/animamea/couchdb-dump

But you can find other tools also:

https://github.com/stockr-labs/couchdbdump

https://github.com/zebooka/couchdb-dump

Comment: It seems a pretty small task to use a tool for. The cURL commands worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: https://github.com/animamea/couchdb-dump didn't work for me :( sed magic inside produces invalid jsons even on a simple docs

Comment: @MaxLobur same here.

Comment: @MaxLobur  on what OS?

Comment: @DanieleB El Capitan

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following command line to convert the output of the curl command to the “docs” structure that the `_bulk_docs` requires:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/mydatabase/_all_docs?include_docs=true' | jq '{"docs": [.rows[].doc]}' | jq 'del(.docs[]._rev)' > db.json
```

[jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the name of an excellent command line processor very useful (i.e. in this situation).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your example using jq was very helpful, thank you!  I also found one of my files was too large to load, and chunking using jq did the trick: `cat db.json | jq '{"docs": .docs[0:30000]}' > db.0-30000.json; cat db.json | jq '{"docs": .docs[30000:]}' > db.30000-.json`

Comment: Is there a way to include the revisions?

Comment: Yes, of course, just drop the `| jq 'del(.docs[]._rev)'` part that removes the revisions. Is that what you need? Note that you wont be able to restore the file if you include the revisions, AFAIK.

Comment: I tried that and many of the records get an error `"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."` as described here: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API . I also tried adding `"new_edits": false` field described in that link, but in that case zero records were loaded without error.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I didn't realize you're talking about the import, not the export. That's exactly the reason why I removed the `_rev` fields in the first place, because of the document conflict. I don't know very much about the way MVCC (multiversion version concurrent control) is handled in CouchDB, so I can't help too much here as I haven't got the need to store more than the current version of the documents. Regards

Answer (score 7):

The reason for your actual error is that you're using `“` instead of plain ASCII `"` around your `-H` argument on the command line.

However, the real solution here is to just copy the `<DATABASE_NAME>.couch` file from the `/path/to/var/lib/couchdb` directory from one server to the other.

Comment: I tried to copy the *.couch files first, but after tying to access the database entries, I received the error, that the database was build with a wrong Erlang version.

Comment: sure! How do I accept? Never the less it was a good and correct answer. I'm obviously not too familiar with this system.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative solution, you may use `couchdb-load` and `couchdb-dump` utilities from [couchdb-python](https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python) project.

Comment: Warning: those do not work with python 3.x (TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes)

Comment: @MaxLobur why not to report about that here https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/issues ? (;

Answer (score 2):

Nolan from the PouchDB team makes some great tools. These will work well to dump and load from CouchDB (including attachments):

**Dump/Backup:**

https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-dump-cli

**Load/Restore:**

https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load

Answer (score 1):

There's also [github.com/danielebailo/couchdb-dump](https://github.com/danielebailo/couchdb-dump) , which might help to clean out old transients, the authors state:

> We've seen 15GB database files, containing only 2.1GB of raw JSON, reduced to 2.5GB on disk after import!

There are also hints on how update_seq works if you want do sync clusters.