# Using pouchdb-load with a local file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, pouchdb

I’m using react to build a .html page facilitating the access to a complicated local file system for the place I work at. This needs to be editable by anyone. I’ve decided to use pouchdb to handle a database which is storing all my buttons with the link attached to them.
This needs to be deployed on multiple computers. The command npm run build works perfectly fine, however, the button database is not shared between the computers, since the pouchdb database is stored in the localstorage.

So I came up with a way to dump the pouch database in a .json file.
The dumping procedure works fine, however when I try to get the data from the .json file using pouchdb-load plugin, I get a CORS error.

```
this.db.load('file:///./tracker.json').then(function () {
  // done loading!
  console.log(this.db)
}).catch(function (err) {
  // HTTP error or something like that
  console.log(err)
});
```

I get an undefined object which is related to a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///tracker.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

message: undefined
name: "unknown"
status: 0
```

When I omit the 'file:///' behind the file path i get the following :

```
yntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:16
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at parseDump (index.js:12)
    at loadString (index.js:32)
    at index.js:87
    at onSuccess (index-browser.js:288)
    at index-browser.js:330
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (index-browser.js:198)
```

The project needs to be build as local .html file since we need to be able open links to files.
What could I do to make pouchdb-load work in such a configuration ?
I'm quite lost at the moment, so any help is appreciated ! What am I doing wrong? Is there any simple trick to open files from the file system without any action from the user ? Is there any other way that I could store a copy of my pouchdb database on the file system ? And if so, how could I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the dreaded CORS error, what a pain! Of course CORS is most necessary, without which local file exploitations would be rife.

The obvious solution is to serve the file over HTTP, either locally - nodejs comes to mind - or serve from a remote server. Here I offer a workaround which is suitable for this use case, maybe not for others.

This solution hinges on two facts: The browser allows the loading of local script files relative to the local document, and `pouchdb-load` supports loading a database from a *string*.

For the benefit of those starting from scratch, let's start with creating a dump of a CouchDB database. I used curl and jq<sup>1,2</sup> to make a dump suitable for import

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5984/sratch/_all_docs?include_docs=true" 
| jq-win64 "{"""docs""": [.rows[].doc]}" > db.js
```

(Above from a VSCode terminal on windows - hence the triple quotes )

OK so now we have an .js file, which for me looks like this

```
{
    docs: [
        {
            _id: "a369bc7329751c1642476e752b000f8d",
            _rev: "1-6a0a8c1a35c6bb106fc3c53cdc99c034",
            id: "4567",
            user: "test2",
            address: {
                city: "New York",
            },
        },
        {
            _id: "a369bc7329751c1642476e752b00290e",
            _rev: "1-29508c896c6c773775c2c46f67714aad",
            id: "4568",
            user: "test2",
            info: {
                city: "Atlanta",
            },
        },
// etc....
```

Of course this is a JSON file with a .js extension.  Why? Let's change the raw JSON into a variable with a quick edit of the dump file:

```
let CANNED_LOCAL_DB = {
        docs: [
            {
                _id: "a369bc7329751c1642476e752b000f8d",
// etc....
```

Excellent, the database is now a JavaScript object.  Let's load it.

Bare bones HTML:

```
<html>    
<body>
  <script src="./db.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/pouchdb.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/pouchdb.memory.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/pouchdb.load.js"></script>
  <script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Here's the index.js code, proving the concept.

```
// "local" db
const ldb = new PouchDB("ldb", { adapter: "memory" });
// load the database from the object, stringified 
    ldb.load(JSON.stringify(CANNED_LOCAL_DB))
        .then(() => {               
            CANNED_LOCAL_DB = undefined;
            return ldb.info();
        })
        .then((info) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(info, undefined, 3));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.toString());
        });
```

The canned db object is set to undefined after load - no reason to let it linger in memory.

Do understand db.js is loaded synchronously, which may have an ugly impact with massive canned db's.  This may be worked around, but is beyond the scope of this answer.

<sup>1</sup> [CouchDB dump to file and load from file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294271/4964791)
<sup>2</sup> [jq, a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294271/4964791)